# How do I compute a realization of h(x) given its PDF and covariance?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, image-processing

[image]

I've added a picture of what I want to compute.  In the nomenclature of the picture, I want to compute a realization of y(x) given the known distributions and constants.

Let's say y(x), random variable, represents the height of a line, with x being the usual x-axis.

The probability distribution function is:

p(y)=K * exp[−(y^2/(2 * s^2)))
i.e. a Gaussian and K and s are known constants

And the autocorrelation of y(x) relative to y(x') is given as:

C = s^2 * exp[−x^2/(2 * R^2)] --> C is the autocorrelation function between y(x) and y(x'), which since the process is stationary will only depend upon the difference between x and x' (i.e. x-x').  Here I replace (x-x') by x.

where R is also a known constant

What I want to do is to compute a realization of y(x). How should I go about doing this?

Given the constraints of the known distributions and constants (s, R, K) I would like to be able to compute a realization of h. Of course, whatever form the computational method takes will involve random numbers. I'm not looking for a deterministic result, just a method to compute a realization of given the knowns. Any advice of what needs to be clarified will be greatly appreciated! Perhaps I should call the covariance function autocorrelation?

Comment: To be more precise what I'd like to do is estimate h(x) given the known information.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have no observation, how do you expect to estimate it? Note that your covariance does not make sense as expressed.

Comment: Given the constraints of the known distributions and constants (s, R, K) I would like to be able to compute a realization of h.  Of course, whatever form the computational method takes will involve random numbers.  I'm not looking for a deterministic result, just a method to compute a realization of given the knowns.  Any advice of what needs to be clarified will be greatly appreciated!  Perhaps I should call the covariance function autocorrelation?

Comment: I think at least two points need clarifying. (1) Your language suggests $h$ may be a *one-dimensional* (no "surface" involved!) *stochastic process* with index parameter $x$, but many other interpretations are possible   (2) The question and your comments ask for various quite different things, ranging from "computing" $h(x)$ to "computing a realization of $h$". That needs further elaboration.

Comment: Good points.  You're right, for simplicity I've chosen a line, and not a surface, and it is a realization of h that I am looking to compute given the information.

Comment: Yes, a Gaussian process as the distribution of h.  I'm not understanding why the autocorrelation is anything but unidimensional.

Comment: To fully describe a Gaussian process, you must supply the correlation between $h(x)$ and $h(x^\prime)$ for any pair of points $x$ and $x^\prime$.  I suspect you may have misinterpreted the text: for a *stationary* process, the correlation will depend only on $x^\prime-x$.  That "lag" is supposed to be the argument to $C$. By listing a pair of arguments $(h,h)$ (which aren't even involved in the formula on the right hand side) you are introducing a confusing, contradictory notation.

Comment: Agreed.  The notation I used was less than ideal given that I'm new to stack exchange and haven't figured out how to format things right.

Comment: So, given the above comments and evolved understanding, can someone help point me in the right direction to computing h(x)?

Comment: No: I fear the problem requires far more background in probability than you have...

Comment: Of course that's true!  Otherwise I wouldn't be seeking help on this forum.  I think I understand the problem, its the solution that's giving me trouble.

Any guidance?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527692/14578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you are trying to generate correlated gaussian variables.

so look up a reference on this. essentially the basic idea is you start by creating a sample from a  multivariate independent gaussian, and then multiply them by the cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix you are trying to reproduce. I would think that many math stat programs would do this for you.